# JQuery Ajax API cannot read property error

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I am trying to use the iRail API (api.irail.be)
I want to implent this in Ionic in a later stage but for now I want to try using it in JQuery using Ajax.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://api.irail.be/stations/?format=json",
}).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res['0'].standardname)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the code I'm using but I get an error that standerdname is not defined and can't be read

I hope someone can help me

Best regards

EDIT: i want to try this but it doesn't work the same way

This is the second thing I want to try and I want to try to get the station

$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.irail.be/liveboard/?id=BE.NMBS.008892007&format=json",
    })
        .done(function(res) {
        console.log(res.liveboard['1'].station); // note res.station here
    });

Also I edited the wrong thing so I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `standardname` property is within the objects held in the `station` array. Therefore your logic should be:

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://api.irail.be/stations/?format=json",
}).done(function(res) {
  console.log(res.station['0'].standardname); // note res.station here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I wonder how can I get the following (added this to the post) working? It seems like it's not the same way

Sorry accidentally edited the wrong thing

Comment: @Ditger I'd suggest starting a new question if you have additional issues you need to clarify